# The action icon is not showing in window for any extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I had built an extension for a game. It worked so that when I went to gameroom, and clicked a game, the site gives new window as a popup. The extension then appeared in the right upper corner of the url. Then I could click and get a tab window in Chrome.

After updating, I don't see the icon (action) anymore. This is not only for my own extension but also two other independently developed extensions don't show the icon anymore. What has happened? How do I get the icon?

My Chrome build version is: 6.0.472.63

Answer (score 0):

Google Chrome is now at version 12+ and any transient browserAction issues with v6 updates should now be solved.